# Pygame translate surface a given amount

Tags: python, pygame, drawing

Does Pygame contain a function similar to Processing.Js's [`translate()`](http://processingjs.org/reference/translate_/) function? I'd like to move items being drawn on the screen without having to update each item's position.

Comment: Are you trying to move everything drawn on the screen over?

Comment: @KSFT Yes, that is ideally what I would like to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question could be clearer, so if I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, you'll need to clarify.

To move everything on the screen over, you can copy the screen, clear the original, then blit the copy at a different location:

```
temp_surf = screen.copy
screen.fill((0,0,0))  # here, you can fill the screen with whatever you want to take the place of what was there before
screen.blit(temp_surf,(x_shift,y_shift))
```

This will move the entire contents of a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object called `screen` over to the right by `x_shift` and down by `y_shift`, filling in the rest of the screen black.